# Add the decimal values which is declared in a string variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @RuleExp as Varchar(max)
,@Val1 Decimal(18,2) = 12.00
,@Val2 Decimal(18,2) = 13.00


select @RuleExp = @Val1 + @Val2
```

I need the sum of the values (i.e) 25. But i get the string value as 12.00 + 13.00.
Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Try:  select @RuleExp = (@Val1 + @Val2)

Comment: do you need the `@rulexp` as varchar and what for?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? What compatibility level? On my Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition SP2 (12.0.5207.0) with compatibility level 120 I get `'25'` in `@RuleExp`, **not** `'12.00 + 13.00'`.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @RuleExp Decimal(18,0)
,@Val1 Decimal(18,2) = 12.00
,@Val2 Decimal(18,2) = 13.00


select @RuleExp = @Val1 + @Val2
select cast(@RuleExp as varchar(max))
```

Comment: Declare as decimal first then cast as string

Comment: Daniel,
This will not results in what am expecting .

Comment: OK see updated - hows that?

Comment: I want that decimal values to be added. but it keep on showing me the same as an expression.

Comment: Not following you - you want the result here to be 25 right?

Comment: yes , i want the value to be 25.

Comment: The above updated code gives you 25

Comment: Thanks for your reply daniel. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
Declare @RuleExp as Varchar(max)
,@Val1 Decimal(18,2) = 12.00
,@Val2 Decimal(18,2) = 13.00


set @RuleExp = @Val1 + @Val2
select @RuleExp
```